# jQuery addclass to links with specific words

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, addclass

How can add a class to an a href tag with specific words?
I want every instance of an a tag with 'click here' and 'more information' to add a class.

```
<a href="">click here</a> <a href="">more information</a>
```

To become:

```
<a href="" class="arrow">click here</a> <a href="" class="arrow">more information</a>
```

Some links have word-breaks on them, causing the "contains" array to miss them:

```
    <a title="Vision and Values" href="/about-us/vision-and-values.aspx">click
here</a>
```

It's not a `<br/>` but the HTML is rendering the two words on separate lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), if you want to exactly match "click here":

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    return text === 'click here' || text === 'more information';
}).addClass('arrow');
```

Or if you have a lot of conditions, use `inArray` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    var whitelist = ['click here', 'more information'];
    var text = $(this).text();
    return $.inArray(text, whitelist) != -1;
}).addClass('arrow');
```

> Because JavaScript treats 0 as loosely equal to false (i.e. 0 ==
>   false, but 0 !== false), if we're checking for the presence of value
>   within array, we need to check if it's not equal to (or greater than)
>   -1.

That way, if you have an additional text to match, you just need to add to that array.

You could also use `contains`, but it will match things like `click here 2` etc, basically anything that `contains` "click here", but not exactly that.

```
$('a:contains(click here),a:contains(more information)').addClass('arrow');
```

Comment: This works fantastically, however some of the "click here" and "more information" links are being missed because of line-breaks between the words. What's the best way of fixing this?

Comment: eh, line break as in `\n` or `\r\n`? `text()` would ignore `<br/>`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector (case sensitive):

```
$("a:contains('click here')").addClass('arrow');
```

Have to use JQuery for this as there's no CSS3 selector that does it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may just need a regular loop, something like:

```
jQuery("a").each(function() {
    var elem = jQuery(this);
    var html = elem.html();
    if (html == "click here" || html == "more information") {
        elem.addClass("arrow");
    }
});
```